# Ranked voting method where unranked candidates on a preference list aren't taken to be the least preferred?

Tags: sorting, permutations, partial-order, ordering, voting

Say there are 5 candidates, A, B, C, D, and E. An election is held using a ranked voting method. That is to say, each voter submits a preference list (the order in which they prefer candidates). E.g. A > B > C > D > E could be my preference list.

For most election schemes, a voter is allowed exclude candidates from their preference list. This usually means that the excluded candidates are their least preferred (with no particular preference between them). E.g. A > B > C implies that both D and E are equally worse than all the other candidates. I will call this the **Bottom Interpretation (BI)**.

However, I think there's another plausible reason one should be able to exclude a candidate: if they are not familiar with that candidate, and therefore do not know how much they prefer it with respect to the candidates they do know. For example, if D and E are movies I haven't watched, then I want excluding them from my list (A > B > C) to signify that they could potentially be ranked anywhere in my list, not necessarily at the bottom. I will call this the **Partial-Ordering Interpretation (POI)**.

Is there any election scheme that uses **POI** when deciding its winner/ordering for the candidates? For an example of what a election scheme that does this should look like:

- 99 voters say A > B > C > D, leaving out E
- 1 voter says that E > A, leaving out the rest

In this case, a scheme that uses **POI** will decide upon a final ordering of E > A > B > C > D. On the other hand, a scheme like instant-run-off voting (IRV) will decide on a final ordering of A > B > C > D > E, because IRV uses **BI**..

Answer (score 0):

I think I realized an answer. The [Schulze Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schulze_method) traditionally uses **BI**. But it can be easily modified to use **POI** instead. All that needs to be done is, when counting how many pairwise preferences there are for candidate A over B, instead of using **BI** (unranked = preferred less), you use **POI** (unranked = no preference). Then the rest of the computation goes on as normal.